# Converting uint8_t* buffer to uint16_t and changing endianness

Tags: c++, endianness, uint8t, uint16

I'd like to process data provided by an external library.

The lib holds the data and provides access to it like this:

```
const uint8_t* data;
std::pair<const uint8_t*, const uint8_t*> getvalue() const {
  return std::make_pair(data + offset, data + length);
}
```

I know that the current data contains two `uint16_t` numbers, but I need to change their endianness.
So altogether the data is 4 bytes long and contains this numbers:

> 66 4 0 0

So I'd like to get two `uint16_t` numbers with `1090` and `0` value respectively.

I can do basic arithmetic and in one place change the endianness:

```
pair<const uint8_t*, const uint8_t*> dataPtrs = library.value();
vector<uint8_t> data(dataPtrs.first, dataPtrs.second);

uint16_t first = data[1] <<8 + data[0]
uint16_t second = data[3]<<8 + data[2]
```

However I'd like to do something more elegant (the vector is replaceable if there is better way for getting the `uint16_t`s).

How can I better create `uint16_t` from `uint8_t*`? I'd avoid memcpy if possible, and use something more modern/safe.

Boost has some nice header-only endian [library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/endian/doc/html/endian.html) which can work, but it needs an `uint16_t` input.

For going further, Boost also provides data types for changing endianness, so I could create a struct:

```
struct datatype {
    big_int16_buf_t     data1;
    big_int16_buf_t     data2;
}
```

Is it possible to *safely* (paddings, platform-dependency, etc) cast a valid, 4 bytes long `uint8_t*` to `datatype`? Maybe with something like this union?

```
typedef union {
    uint8_t u8[4];
    datatype correct_data;
} mydata;
```

Comment: Reinterpret-casting via a union is not allowed in C++ (other than between corresponding members of standard-layout structs). That's a Cism only. You'd need to `memcpy()` or from C++20 `std::bit_cast()`.

Comment: @underscore_d You can't `std::bit_cast` from a pointer (unless you're bit casting the pointer value rather than pointed objects).

Comment: @eerorika Well, yeah, but you could deref the pointer to get bytes and then bit_cast those bytes to the desired type. I was proceeding from the final bit of code, which is using values.

Comment: @underscore_d If you indirect through a `std::uint8_t*`, then you get a `std::uint8_t` which is not of correct size to be bit_casted into `std::uint16_t`  (nor into `datatype`). I don't see how bit_cast could be used here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Maybe with something like this union?

No. Type punning with unions is not well defined in C++.

This would work assuming `big_int16_buf_t` and therefore `datatype` is trivially copiable:

```
datatype d{};
std::memcpy(&d, data, sizeof d);
```

> ```
> uint16_t first = data[1] <<8 + data[0]
> uint16_t second = data[3]<<8 + data[2]
> ```
>
> However I'd like to do something more elegant

This is actually (subjectively, in my opinion) quite an elegant way because it works the same way on all systems. This reads the data as little endian, whether the CPU is little, big or some other endian. This is well portable.

> However I'd like to do something more elegant (the vector is replaceable if there is better way for getting the uint16_ts).

The vector seems entirely pointless. You could just as well use:

```
const std::uint8_t* data = dataPtrs.first;
```

Comment: Is the `memcpy` approach worse in terms of _portability_ compared to the manual bitwise method?

Comment: @Daniel Memcopy into `uint16_t` would not be good because result would depend on native endianness. I don't know how `big_int16_buf_t` works excatly, so I'm not sure if memcpying into it does what one would want. It might be just fine.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I better create `uint16_t` from `uint8_t*`?

If you are **certain** that the data sitting behind the `uint8_t` pointer is truly a `uint16_t`, C++ allows: `auto u16 = *static_cast<uint16_t const*>(data);` **Otherwise, this is UB.**

Given a big [endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) value, transforming this into little endian can be done with the [`ntohs`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ntohs) function (under linux, other OSes have similar functions).

---

**But beware**, if the pointer you hold points to two individual `uint8_t` values, you **mustn't** convert them by pointer-cast. In that case, you have to manually specify which value goes where (conceivably with a function template). This will be the most portable solution, and in all likelihood the compiler will create efficient code out of the shifts and ors.